# JavaScript change input field border color when detect one of specific inputs

Tags: javascript, html

This is not a duplicate, I've done a lot of research and found nothing that would work for me
I need my input field border color to change everytime specific input was detected, but it doesn't work. JS here

**Edit: Fixed some stupid mistakes**

```
function zmenitBarvu() {
    var inputVal = document.getElementsById("cisla");
    if (inputVal.value == "0") {
         inputVal.setAttribute( 'style', 'border: 5px solid #f5d442 !important;');
    }
    if (inputVal.value == "2") {
         inputVal.setAttribute( 'style', 'border: 5px solid #f5d442 !important;');
    }
    else {
        inputVal.setAttribute( 'style', 'border: 1px solid #ccc !important;');
    }
}
```

*Please help*

HTML here

```
<div class="form">
    <form id="cisla"> 
        <input name="cislo1" type="text" class="cisla" placeholder="" id="cislo1" autofocus onkeyup="if (/\D/g.test(this.value)) this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/g,'')" oninput="cislo1.value=cislo1.value.slice(0,2)" /><br>
        <input name="cislo2" type="text" class="cisla" placeholder="" id="cislo2" /><br>
        <input name="cislo3" type="text" class="cisla" placeholder="" id="cislo3" /><br>
        <input name="cislo4" type="text" class="cisla" placeholder="" id="cislo4" /><br>
        <input name="cislo5" type="text" class="cisla" placeholder="" id="cislo5" /><br>
        <input name="cislo6" type="text" class="cisla" placeholder="" id="cislo6" /><br>
        <input name="cislo7" type="text" class="cisla" placeholder="" id="cislo7" /><br>
        <input name="cislo8" type="text" class="cisla" placeholder="" id="cislo8" /><br>
        <input name="cislo9" type="text" class="cisla" placeholder="" id="cislo9" /><br>
        <input name="cislo10" type="text" class="cisla" placeholder="" id="cislo10" /><br>
        <input name="cislo11" type="text" class="cisla" placeholder="" id="cislo11" /><br>
        <input name="cislo12" type="text" class="cisla" placeholder="" id="cislo12" /><br>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: `var inputVal = document.getElementsByClassName("cisla");` What element are you trying to select here? I see no elements with `class="cisla"`. Also, `class=cislo1` without quotes is not valid syntax. `getElementsByClassName` returns a list of elements, not a singular element - maybe you meant to iterate through the list instead

Comment: Even fixing class `cisla` I bet that the problem occurs only for `inputVal.value == "0"`, am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few issues:

- cisla is an id, not a class name
- you don't have any event binded to your zmenitBarvu function
- you aren't applying the borders to the input elements themselves nor checking the values on them, but only the form with id cisla
- else will overwrite styles set when "0" is matched with value, because else is on anything that's not "2" only.  You need to chain the else if so only one executes.

Demo using [event delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate).  I recommend just using the same class name so they use the same selector for class, and same name (unless form data requires incremented names), and not using an id at all, since it's unnecessary.  I'm using cislo prefixed class name input elements selector to match elements:

```js
function zmenitBarvu() {
    document.getElementById("cisla").addEventListener('input',event=>{
    var inputVal = event.target;
    if(!inputVal.matches('input[class^=cislo]')) return;

    if (inputVal.value === "0") {
         inputVal.setAttribute( 'style', 'border: 5px solid #f5d442 !important;');
    }
    else if (inputVal.value === "2") {
         inputVal.setAttribute( 'style', 'border: 5px solid #f5d442 !important;');
    }
    else {
        inputVal.setAttribute( 'style', 'border: 1px solid #ccc !important;');
    }

    });
}
zmenitBarvu()
```

```html
<div class="form">
    <form id="cisla"> 
        <input name="cislo1" type="text" class=cislo1 placeholder="" id="cislo1" autofocus onkeyup="if (/\D/g.test(this.value)) this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/g,'')" oninput="cislo1.value=cislo1.value.slice(0,2)" /><br>
        <input name="cislo2" type="text" class=cislo2 placeholder="" id="cislo2" /><br>
        <input name="cislo3" type="text" class=cislo3 placeholder="" id="cislo3" /><br>
        <input name="cislo4" type="text" class=cislo4 placeholder="" id="cislo4" /><br>
        <input name="cislo5" type="text" class=cislo5 placeholder="" id="cislo5" /><br>
        <input name="cislo6" type="text" class=cislo6 placeholder="" id="cislo6" /><br>
        <input name="cislo7" type="text" class=cislo7 placeholder="" id="cislo7" /><br>
        <input name="cislo8" type="text" class=cislo8 placeholder="" id="cislo8" /><br>
        <input name="cislo9" type="text" class=cislo9 placeholder="" id="cislo9" /><br>
        <input name="cislo10" type="text" class=cislo10 placeholder="" id="cislo10" /><br>
        <input name="cislo11" type="text" class=cislo11 placeholder="" id="cislo11" /><br>
        <input name="cislo12" type="text" class=cislo12 placeholder="" id="cislo12" /><br>
    </form>
</div>
```

Demo based on fixing your original attempt, that binds to every child of the cisla form.

```js
function zmenitBarvu() {
    document.getElementById("cisla").childNodes.forEach(inputVal=>{
    inputVal.addEventListener('input',event=>{
    if (inputVal.value == "0") {
         inputVal.setAttribute( 'style', 'border: 5px solid #f5d442 !important;');
    }
    else if (inputVal.value == "2") {
         inputVal.setAttribute( 'style', 'border: 5px solid #f5d442 !important;');
    }
    else {
        inputVal.setAttribute( 'style', 'border: 1px solid #ccc !important;');
    }
    });
    });
}
zmenitBarvu()
```

```html
<div class="form">
    <form id="cisla"> 
        <input name="cislo1" type="text" class=cislo1 placeholder="" id="cislo1" autofocus onkeyup="if (/\D/g.test(this.value)) this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/g,'')" oninput="cislo1.value=cislo1.value.slice(0,2)" /><br>
        <input name="cislo2" type="text" class=cislo2 placeholder="" id="cislo2" /><br>
        <input name="cislo3" type="text" class=cislo3 placeholder="" id="cislo3" /><br>
        <input name="cislo4" type="text" class=cislo4 placeholder="" id="cislo4" /><br>
        <input name="cislo5" type="text" class=cislo5 placeholder="" id="cislo5" /><br>
        <input name="cislo6" type="text" class=cislo6 placeholder="" id="cislo6" /><br>
        <input name="cislo7" type="text" class=cislo7 placeholder="" id="cislo7" /><br>
        <input name="cislo8" type="text" class=cislo8 placeholder="" id="cislo8" /><br>
        <input name="cislo9" type="text" class=cislo9 placeholder="" id="cislo9" /><br>
        <input name="cislo10" type="text" class=cislo10 placeholder="" id="cislo10" /><br>
        <input name="cislo11" type="text" class=cislo11 placeholder="" id="cislo11" /><br>
        <input name="cislo12" type="text" class=cislo12 placeholder="" id="cislo12" /><br>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: You're just awesome, ain't you? Working, thank you, appreciate